# Why is “but koalas are lighter” a subordinate clause in this sentence?

Tags: clauses, subordinate-clauses

This is exactly how the sentence is presented:

> If you ask me, pandas are far cuter than koalas but koalas are lighter.

So I was required to split this into its clauses, and categorise them.

“If you ask me” = Subordinating Clause (the comma is the sub. conjunction.)

“pandas are far cuter than koalas” - Main Clause

“But koalas a lighter”   - I said that this was a Main clause as it is connected to a main clause by the conjunction “but”, which I thought would be a coordinating conjunction, hence suggesting that that clause was a main one.

However, the textbook says that that is actually a subordinate clause.

Why is this the case?

Comment: You are correct; probably an error in the book.

Comment: You have two independent (main) clauses coordinated with *but*. So the text book must be wrong, as @Cerberus_Reinstate_Monica says.

Comment: The textbook is wrong _pandas are far cuter than koalas_ and  _but koalas are lighter_ are both main (independent) clauses.